# Is there any way to do group-by and count at once in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Assume that there is a sequence like below:

```
["ab" "ba" "ac" "ca" "bc" "cc"]
```

I want to know the frequencies but the key should be sorted string. In short, I want to get the result like this:

```
{"ab" 2, "ac" 2, "bc" 1, "cc" 1}
```

Clojure has `frequencies` function, but it doesn't accept key function.
So, usually I can do this by the combination of `group-by` and `map`:

```
(->> ["ab" "ba" "ac" "ca" "bc" "cc"]
     (group-by #(apply str (sort %)))
     (map (fn [[k vs]] [k (count vs)]))
     (int {}))
```

But, this looks verbose. Even in Java, I can do grouping and counting at the same time with Stream API, like this: (Assuming that there is a method `sortedStr(s)`

```
Arrays.asList("aa", "ab", "ab", "bb", "cc" , "ca")
  .stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(s->sortedStr(s), counting()));
```

Is there any way to group-by and counting at once in clojure like Java8?

Comment: I might have missed something or misunderstood but what about [frequencies](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/frequencies)?

Comment: @Asthor As you can see in the document on `frequencies`, it only accepts `coll` as its argument. You cannot specify the key function.

Comment: @ntalbs you really don't need a special "key handling" function, all it will do is simply `map` it over your `coll` before running. This is something you can do by yourself as the answer below shows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Stefan answer works well, but it is not the most efficient, because it first maps over the coll (producing an intermediate collection) and then finds frequencies. So it doesn't really conform to "group-by and count at once" part of your question. I would rather go with `reduce`:

```
user> (reduce #(update %1 (apply str (sort %2)) (fnil inc 0))
              {} ["ab" "ba" "ac" "ca" "bc" "cc"])
{"ab" 2, "ac" 2, "bc" 1, "cc" 1}
```

Comment: This looks a little harder for me to understand, especially `fnil` function. But once I understand, this looks better. Also I can apply this method to do group by and sum at once, which is actually what I wanted. Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Here is a Clojure version using the built-in `frequencies` function.

```
 (frequencies (map #(apply str (sort %)) 
                   ["ab" "ba" "ac" "ca" "bc" "cc"]))
 ;;=> {"ab" 2, "ac" 2, "bc" 1, "cc" 1}
```

I may be wrong, but the Java version already gets the sorted keys in your example.  In that case, it would be just a call to `frequencies` in Clojure (if I understood your question correctly).

EDIT: Looks like the Java version was corrected in the meantime, so my last comment becomes obsolete.

Comment: You understand the question correctly. Perhaps I failed to describe my requirement properly. I think I have to ask another question. Anyway, `map` over the items first, then apply `frequencies` looks much better than the way I used in the question. Thanks.